# Can I add UIActivityViewController to my ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am working on a photo share button same as a default "Photos" app.

When I click on the share button it is added as SubView (uiactivityviewcontroller/uiactivityviewcontroller.view)in my viewcontroller?

[image: Example Image]

My Code:

```
   let text = "This is some text that I want to share."

    // set up activity view controller
    let textToShare = [ text ]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
    //activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ .airDrop,.postToFacebook ]

    // present the view controller
    if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone){
       self.containerView.addSubview(activityViewController.view)
    }else{
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

But this code gives me the error **UIActivityViewController can only be used modally or as contentViewController in popover on iPad.**

Is there a better solution?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Is your application rootVC embed with NavigationController?

Comment: @karthikeyan Yes

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/813044-uiactivityviewcontroller-tutorial-sharing-data

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
self.containerView.addSubview(activityViewController.view)
```

That is illegal (in several ways!). You must present the activity view controller, like this:

```
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: i know that. but in my case not present activityViewController add in my UIViewController same as a screenshot in question.

Comment: There is no “in my case”. There is only one way to use an activity view controller and I have just told you what it is.

Comment: i create share button same as a  default(iPhone & IPad) "Photos" app.

Comment: The Photos app does what I am saying. It calls `present` when you tap the share button, to show the activity view controller. You must do that too. There is no point arguing! Do what I say or you will crash.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation you should modally present activity Controller

> The system provides several standard services, such as copying items
>   to the pasteboard, posting content to social media sites, sending
>   items via email or SMS, and more. Apps can also define custom
>   services. Your app is responsible for configuring, presenting, and
>   dismissing this view controller. Configuration for the view controller
>   involves specifying the data objects on which the view controller
>   should act. (You can also specify the list of custom services your app
>   supports.) When presenting the view controller, you must do so using
>   the appropriate means for the current device. On iPad, you must
>   present the view controller in a popover. **On iPhone and iPod touch,
>   you must present it modally**.

For more info [Click here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller)

Comment: Same as what I said.

Comment: You have answered before me so i have shared documentation link